# connect to specific wifi using native wifi profile corrupted error

Tags: c#, .net, wireless, wifi

I am using the NativeWifi API to connect to a specific wireless network but I seem to get the profile is corrupted error. I have tried connecting without overriding the profile but that doesn't work either. I know that my ssid and the password is correct. I thought the mac I was reading was incorrect but at this point I have tried all macs I can think of. I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Most of the code was what I found online but I can't find why this working solution won't work for me. keep in mind that the connection I am trying to make is to my phone hotstop.

FYI: I have tried all the duplicate question suggestions but the solutions wouldn't work for me.

```
WlanClient client = new WlanClient();

            foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces)
            {
                if (wlanIface.CurrentConnection.profileName == "AndroidAP")
                {
                    if (wlanIface.CurrentConnection.isState == Wlan.WlanInterfaceState.Connected)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Already connected to AndroidAP");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                }
                // Retrieves XML configurations of existing profiles.
                // This can assist you in constructing your own XML configuration
                // (that is, it will give you an example to follow).
                foreach (Wlan.WlanProfileInfo profileInfo in wlanIface.GetProfiles())
                {
                    string name = profileInfo.profileName; // this is typically the network's SSID                    
                    string xml = wlanIface.GetProfileXml(profileInfo.profileName);
                }

                string mac = String.Empty;
                foreach (Wlan.WlanBssEntry network2 in wlanIface.GetNetworkBssList())
                {
                    byte[] macAddr = network2.dot11Bssid;
                    if (GetStringForSSID(network2.dot11Ssid) == "AndroidAP")
                    {                        
                        for (int i = 0; i < macAddr.Length - 1; i++)
                        {
                            mac += macAddr[i].ToString("x2").PadLeft(2, '0').ToUpper();
                        }

                        // Connects to a known network with WEP security
                        string profileName = "AndroidAP"; // this is also the SSID                        
                        string key = "password";

                        string profileXml = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><WLANProfile xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1\"><name>{0}</name><SSIDConfig><SSID><hex>{1}</hex><name>{0}</name></SSID></SSIDConfig><connectionType>ESS</connectionType><MSM><security><authEncryption><authentication>open</authentication><encryption>WEP</encryption><useOneX>false</useOneX></authEncryption><sharedKey><keyType>networkKey</keyType><protected>false</protected><keyMaterial>{2}</keyMaterial></sharedKey><keyIndex>0</keyIndex></security></MSM></WLANProfile>", profileName, mac, key);

                        //wlanIface.SetProfile(Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, profileXml, true);
                        wlanIface.Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Any, profileName);
                    }                    
                }                
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [SSIDConfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms707363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
you should not provide the mac address in `<hex></hex>` element but the hex representation of `<name></name>`.

Also note(from link above):

> Although the hex and name elements are optional, at least one hex or name element must appear as a child of the SSID element.